# unable to using winapp

Tags: selenium, appium, winapp, winappdriver

I am unable to run the code

```
capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");
CalculatorSession = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities);
```

this code opens the calculator app but it say IOSDriver is wrong

[Original code](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/master/Samples/Java/CalculatorTest/src/test/java/CalculatorTest.java)

I changed just two lines of the code

Software: Java, Eclipse, WinappDriver

I am automating Windows application in Windows 10

Comment: This looks like you're using Appium?  If so, you should tag that as well.  To better understand what you're encountering, I'd need to see more of the code, please.

Comment: thanks i added the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the above problem updating the driver manual rather than taking the auto-suggestion version in maven